# Splash not rendering a webpage completely

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I am trying to use scrapy + splash to **scrape** this site https://www.teammitsubishihartford.com/new-inventory/index.htm?compositeType=new. But i am unable to extract any data from the site. When I try rendering the webpage using splash api (browser), I came to know that the site is not fully loaded (splash rendering returns a partially loaded website image). How can I render the site completly??

Answer (score 0):

@Vinu Abraham, If your requirement is not specific to scrapy + splash, you can use selenium. This issue occurs when we try to scrape a dynamic site.
Below is the code snippet for reference.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import re
from csv import writer

# url of the page we want to scrape
url = 'https://www.*******/drugs-all-medicines'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
all_divs = soup.find('div', {'class': 'style__container___1i8GI'})
```

Also let me know if you get any solution for the same using scrapy.

Comment: I was able to scrape the site using selenium.. My my primary intention was to scrap using splash + scrapy. Also, isn't splash used to scrap render and scrap dynamic pages.